# How to configure Spring SimpleMessageListenerContainer receiveTimeout in order to scale up to a reasonable number of consumers

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Use case
A backend consuming messages at various rate and inserting the messages in a DB.
Today in production my SimpleMessageListenerContainer scales to maxConcurrentConsumers **even if is not necessary to handle the traffic rate.**

Problem
I try to find the proper configuration of spring SimpleMessageListenerContainer in order to let spring scale up/down the number of consumers to the adequate number in order to handle the incoming traffic.

With a a fix injection rate, on a single node rabbitmq I have noticed that the scaling process stabilize at
numberOfConsumers = (injectionRate * receiveTimeoutInMilliseconds) / 1000

For example :
injection rate : 100 msg/s
`container.setReceiveTimeout(100L);  // 100 ms` 
--> consumers 11
--> Consumer capacity 100%

injection rate : 100 msg/s
`container.setReceiveTimeout(1000L);   // 1 s  - default` 
--> consumers 101
--> Consumer capacity 100%

Knowing that more consumers means more threads and more amqp channels
**I am wondering why the scaling algorithm is not linked to the consumerCapacity metric and why is the default receive timeout set to 1 second ?**

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#listener-concurrency

> In addition, a new property called `maxConcurrentConsumers` has been added and the container dynamically adjusts the concurrency based on workload. This works in conjunction with four additional properties: `consecutiveActiveTrigger`, `startConsumerMinInterval`, `consecutiveIdleTrigger`, and `stopConsumerMinInterval`. With the default settings, the algorithm to increase consumers works as follows:

> If the `maxConcurrentConsumers` has not been reached and an existing consumer is active for ten consecutive cycles AND at least 10 seconds has elapsed since the last consumer was started, a new consumer is started. A consumer is considered active if it received at least one message in `batchSize * receiveTimeout` milliseconds.

> With the default settings, the algorithm to **decrease** consumers works as follows:

> If there are more than `concurrentConsumers` running and a consumer detects ten consecutive timeouts (idle) AND the last consumer was stopped at least 60 seconds ago, a consumer is stopped. The timeout depends on the `receiveTimeout` and the `batchSize` properties. A consumer is considered idle if it receives no messages in `batchSize * receiveTimeout` milliseconds. So, with the default timeout (one second) and a batchSize of four, stopping a consumer is considered after 40 seconds of idle time (four timeouts correspond to one idle detection).

> Practically, consumers can be stopped only if the whole container is idle for some time. This is because the broker shares its work across all the active consumers.

So, when you reduce the `receiveTimeout` you would need a corresponding increase in the idle/active triggers.

The default is 1 second to provide a reasonable compromise between spinning an idle consumer while retaining responsive behavior to a container `stop()` operation (idle consumers are blocked for the timeout). Increasing it will cause a less responsive container (for `stop()`).

It is generally unnecessary to set it lower than 1 second.